# Using an OGM with AWS Neptune

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, goblin

I can't seem to find any resources that state whether or not some popular OGMs can be used with neptune instead of writing raw gremlin queries for example.

Would any of you know what OGMs are supported or can be used with Neptune and which would you recommend for python in particular?

Also, would it be better to use an OGM (like goblin for example) or stick to the gremlin python GVL instead?

Answer (score 0):

Goblin claims that its TP 3.2.4 compatible, but I don't see any mention of its plan to be in sync with newer TP versions. GLV's ensure that you always have a compatibility with any TP version that has been released. They need not work across versions (ie. GLV v3.2.4 might not work peacefully with a TP 3.3.0 server) but you be sure that there will be a GLV for each official release of TP.

Barring that, I don't see any concerns using an OGM. Its a different paradigm at the end of the day and should not be a concern apart from the version compatibility that I called out before. I've not tried it in person, so do let me know how it goes! Good luck.